# make players change after certain time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I want to add the following functionality in a tictactoe game: if a player is on turn but he/she doesn't do anything for a certain time (10 seconds), than it's the another player's turn.

In the "GameHub" class (extends a Server class for creating only one game) I have the inner class "GameState", which maintains the current state of the game and passes it as a message to the server (and then it is forwarded to all clients/players).

```
public class GameHub extends Server {

private GameState state;

public GameHub(int port) throws IOException {
    super(port);
    state = new GameState();
    setAutoreset(true);
}

protected void messageReceived(int playerID, Object message) {
    state.applyMessage(playerID, message);
    sendToAll(state);
}

protected void playerConnected(int playerID) {
    if (getPlayerList().length == 2) {
        shutdownServerSocket();
        state.startFirstGame();
        sendToAll(state);
    }
}

protected void playerDisconnected(int playerID) {
    state.playerDisconnected = true;
    sendToAll(state);
}

public static class GameState implements Serializable {

    public boolean playerDisconnected;

    public char[][] board;

    public boolean gameInProgress;

    public int playerPlayingX;
    public int playerPlayingO;
    public int currentPlayer;

    public boolean gameEndedInTie;
    public int winner;

    public void applyMessage(int sender, Object message) {        

        if (gameInProgress && message instanceof int[] && sender == currentPlayer) {
            int[] move = (int[]) message;
            if (move == null || move.length != 2) {
                return;
            }
            int row = move[0];
            int col = move[1];
            if (row < 0 || row > 2 || col < 0 || col > 2 || board[row][col] != ' ') {
                return;
            }

            board[row][col] = (currentPlayer == playerPlayingX) ? 'X' : 'O';

            if (winner()) {
                gameInProgress = false;
                winner = currentPlayer;
            } else if (tie()) {
                gameInProgress = false;
                gameEndedInTie = true;
            } 

            else {
                currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == playerPlayingX) ? playerPlayingO : playerPlayingX;
            }

        } else if (!gameInProgress && message.equals("newgame")) {
            startGame();
        }
    }

    void startFirstGame() {
        startGame();
    }

    private void startGame() {
        board = new char[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        int xPlr = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 1 : 2;
        playerPlayingX = xPlr;  // Will be 1 or 2.
        playerPlayingO = 3 - xPlr;  // The other player ( 3 - 1 = 2, and 3 - 2 = 1 )
        currentPlayer = playerPlayingX;
        gameEndedInTie = false;
        winner = -1;
        gameInProgress = true;
    }

    private boolean winner() {
        if (board[0][0] != ' '
                && (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2])) {
            return true;
        }
        if (board[0][2] != ' '
                && (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            if (board[row][0] != ' '
                    && (board[row][0] == board[row][1] && board[row][1] == board[row][2])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            if (board[0][col] != ' '
                    && (board[0][col] == board[1][col] && board[1][col] == board[2][col])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean tie() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == ' ') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

For the time measurement I have the "Countdown" class, which aim is to change the players after the required time elapsed.

```
     public class Countdown {

        int timer;

        public void counter(int timeFrame) {

            timer = timeFrame;

            Timer TimerA = new Timer();
            TimerTask TaskA = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (timer >= 0) {
                        timer--;
                    }
                    if (timer == -1) {
                        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == playerPlayingX) ? playerPlayingO : playerPlayingX;
                        TimerA.cancel();
                    }

                }
            };
            TimerA.schedule(TaskA, 0, 1000);
        }

        public int getTimer(){
            return timer;
        }

    }
```

Exactly at that part I'm stuck. In my opinion I need to add and start the timer somewhere in the "GameState" class, but for some reason I can't figure it out where exactly.

```
int timeFrame = 10;
Countdown C = new Countdown();
C.counter(timeFrame);
```

I thought it should be started in that "else block"

```
else {currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == playerPlayingX) ? playerPlayingO : playerPlayingX;
int timeFrame = 10;
Countdown C = new Countdown();
C.counter(timeFrame);}
```

But it doesn't work properly => it works just for "playerPlayingO" (if he delays 10 seconds, he misses his turn). playerPlayingX is not affected...

May be I'm also missing something else...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a JavaFX you may use a [task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for this - Just make the task run something like this:

```
Thread.sleep(10000); //Wait 10 Secs
if (activePlayer == initialActivePlayer) switchPlayer(); //Better write your own "ShouldWeSwitch"-Condition
```

You may need to fiddle around with synchronization a little and maybe terminate the tasks when the players trigger the switch but this may work for your game.

PS: If you're not using JavaFX you can simply make your own Task by creating a class that extends [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)